# Is there a limit to the size of an unordered set in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

I am parsing a text file with a word and a tag (looks like word/tag). I am trying to find the number of unique tags in my file and am using an unordered set in C++ to insert tags. However I seem to be randomly getting this exception: “EXC_I386_GPFLT" upon inserting (after an undetermined number of inserts) into my unordered set. I don't think I am running out of memory because Xcode says I'm only using ~300 - 400 KB.

Here is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ParseTrain.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ParseTrain p("~/Desktop/treebank.5290.train");
    std::cout<<"The Number of Tags is: "<<p.getSizeOfTag()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my ParseTrain.cpp:

```
#include "ParseTrain.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


ParseTrain::ParseTrain(std::string fName){
    std::ifstream file(fName);
    std::string word;

    if(!file)
        return;

    //read file by word
    while(file >> word ){
        char * cWord = new char (word.size()+1);
        std::strcpy(cWord,word.c_str());

        char *p = std::strtok(cWord, "/");
        std::string key = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        std::string value = p;
        std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
        _tag.insert(value);//getting exception thrown after undeterminable number of inserts at this line
        delete [] cWord;
        cWord = NULL;
    }
}
```

Here is my ParseTrain.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

class ParseTrain{
private:

    //map to relate the work and part of speech tag
    std::vector <std::map<std::string, std::string>> _sentence;
    std::unordered_set<std::string> _tag;
public:

    //constructor to parse file
    //takes in path to file to parse
    ParseTrain(std::string fName);

    inline size_t getSizeOfTag(){
        return _tag.size();
    }
};
```

And finally here is a small part of the text file I am trying to parse and get the tags:

```
Pierre/NP Vinken/NP ,/, 61/CD years/NNS old/JJ ,/, will/MD join/VB the/DT board/NN as/IN a/DT nonexecutive/JJ director/NN Nov./NP 29/CD ./. 
Mr./NP Vinken/NP is/VBZ chairman/NN of/IN Elsevier/NP N.V./NP ,/, the/DT Dutch/NP publishing/VBG group/NN ./.
```

I really can't figure out why the exception is being thrown upon inserting. The only thing I can think of is that there might be a limit to the size of an unordered set but that seems strange considering I'm using such little memory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is always a limit.  But most likely your trying to read from value when *P == nullptr.  Shorten your string and just use the last part.  Then it wont take so long to step through the code and inspect the locals.  You should handle the case where strtok is returning null.

Comment: Memory can't be truly unlimited, but code filled with `strtok`, raw `new`, and raw `delete` leads to lots of much more likely targets.

Comment: The obvious way to debug this is to put some error checking in the parsing code: after `strtok` you just assume the pointers aren't NULL - what if there's a bad line in the input?  You could add a counter so you know which line of input's involved - useful if printing every line is too slow to be practical (even to a file or `tail`).  Better yet, use `std::string::find` and `erase` or `substr` to extract the value.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
char * cWord = new char (word.size()+1);
```

should be this:

```
char * cWord = new char [word.size()+1];
```

Note the brackets.

The first one allocates a single byte, and initializes it to `word.size()+1`. The second one allocates `word.size()+1` bytes.